# style tag in xslt not rendering

Tags: css, xml, xslt

Here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
        <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<xsl:call-template name="header">
<xsl:with-param name="title">Strip Club List - Top 100 
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'">
    Highest Number of Comments
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numreviews'">
    Highest Number of Reviews
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='highestreviews'">
    Highest Rating
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numlikes'">
    Highest Number of Likes
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numdislikes'">
    Highest Number of Dislikes
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numfollowers'">
    Highest Number of Followers
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:value-of select="/*/locations/name" /></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="stylesheets">fonts.css,core.css,state.css,top.css</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="scripts">core.js,state.js</xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'">
        <style>
            .linked_location .rating {
                right: 110px;        
            }
        </style>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numreviews'">
        <style>
            .linked_location .rating {
                right: 100px;        
            }
        </style>
    </xsl:when>     
    </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <body>
    <div id="body"></div>
    </body>
   </html>
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its being rendered in the head of the html document. The problem is that its not rendering onto the page. I believe it has to do with using `style tags` in an `XSLT document`.

XML:

```
  <root>
  <general>
 <viewmethod>numreviews</viewmethod>
 </general>
 </root>
```

I also just tried:

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'">
    <style>
        .linked_location .rating {
            right: 110px;        
        }
    </style>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numreviews'">
    &lt;style&gt;
        .linked_location .rating {
            right: 100px;        
        }
    &lt;/style&gt;
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='highestreviews'">
    &lt;style&gt;
        .linked_location .rating {
            right: 100px;        
        }
    &lt;/style&gt;
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numlikes'">
    &lt;style&gt;
        .linked_location .rating {
            right: 90px;         
        }
    &lt;/style&gt;
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numdislikes'">
    &lt;style&gt;
        .linked_location .rating {
            right: 90px;         
        }
    &lt;/style&gt;
</xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numfollowers'">
    &lt;style&gt;
        .linked_location .rating {
            right: 90px;         
        }
    &lt;/style&gt;
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

here is my `header template`

```
<xsl:template name="header">
<xsl:param name="title" />
<xsl:param name="keywords" />
<xsl:param name="description" />
<xsl:param name="stylesheets" />
<xsl:param name="scripts" />
<xsl:param name="emp" />
<head>
<xsl:if test="string-length($keywords) &gt; 0"><meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords}" /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="string-length($description) &gt; 0"><meta name="description" content="{$description}" /></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="string-length($stylesheets) &gt; 0"><xsl:call-template name="headercss"><xsl:with-param name="stylesheets" select="$stylesheets" /></xsl:call-template></xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="string-length($scripts) &gt; 0"><xsl:call-template name="headerjs"><xsl:with-param name="scripts" select="$scripts" /></xsl:call-template></xsl:if>
<script src="http://domain/www/delivery/i.php?id=13&#38;blockcampaign=1&#38;target=_blank"></script>
<xsl:if test="$emp &gt; 0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/emp/style.css" />
<script src="/emp/gl.js"></script>
<script src="/emp/tween.js"></script>
<script src="/emp/emp.js"></script>
</xsl:if>
<title><xsl:value-of select="$title" /></title>

</head>
</xsl:template>
```

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @michael.hor257k please look at the updated question

Comment: Do you really not understand that the problem cannot be reproduced with only that snippet to go by?

Comment: @michael.hor257k this update should suffice that issue.

Comment: @michael.hor257k see latest update

Comment: There's some issues with your XSLT.  `<xsl:call-template>` can't have an `<xsl:choose>` as a child - if you move your choose block out of the call-template block it works fine (except that there's no template named `header`).  voting to close since this really seems like a typographical/code formatting issue - unless you're trying to ask about how call-templates work and don't understand why your usage here doesn't.

Comment: @DanField Thats incorrect. I updated my XSLT. I am using `xsl:choose` within the `xsl:call-template` just fine. This specifically has to do with my question in detail, `style`. I think I need to use <xsl:with-param name="style"> but thats not working either. Please delete your vote to close.

Comment: @jkushner: check these out.  The first uses your XSLT as posted, the second removes the invalid call template: http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5X and http://xsltransform.net/94rmq5X/1 - if you still have a question after providing some syntactically valid XSLT then ask away, but it'd be a different question than this one.

Comment: @DanField i added the header template.

Comment: Your `<xsl:call-template>` tag is still invalid - it's not allowed to contain `<xsl:choose>`.  If you have a processor that's allowing it it's non-standard and you're getting unpredictable results.  Again,t ry moving your `<xsl:choose>` outside the call template and you might be fine...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments `xsl:choose` can not be a child of `xsl:call-template`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#named-templates for the syntax. It is possible that the XSLT processor you are using is simply ignoring the `xsl:choose` in this case, rather than throwing an error.

What you probably need to do, is add a `style` parameter to your `header` template, and then pass in the style using `xsl:with-param` in a similar manner to the other parameters.

Try this XSLT as a slimmed down example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <xsl:call-template name="header">
            <xsl:with-param name="title">Test</xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="keywords" select="/root/general/viewmethod" />
            <xsl:with-param name="style">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numcomments'">
                    <style>
                        .linked_location .rating {
                            right: 110px;        
                        }
                    </style>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="/*/general/viewmethod='numreviews'">
                    <style>
                        .linked_location .rating {
                            right: 100px;        
                        }
                    </style>
                </xsl:when>     
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <body>
            <div id="body"></div>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="header">
    <xsl:param name="title" />
    <xsl:param name="keywords" />
    <xsl:param name="style" />
    <head>
        <xsl:if test="string-length($keywords) &gt; 0"><meta name="keywords" content="{$keywords}" /></xsl:if>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$style" />
        <title><xsl:value-of select="$title" /></title>
    </head>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```